Purpose of Additional Resistor in a Wheatstone Bridge and Differential Amplifier Circuit with Platinum RTD (R9)
The combination of a Wheatstone bridge and a differential amplifier circuit is quite common. However, I encountered a circuit (shown in the diagram) with a unique configuration. In this design, an additional resistor (R8) is connected between one output terminal of the Wheatstone bridge and the output of the differential amplifier. Here, R9 represents the platinum resistance thermometer (RTD) being measured.
I am trying to understand the role of this additional resistor, R8, and the reasoning behind this design choice. When analyzing the circuit, I noticed that varying the value of R8 affects the relationship between the output voltage and the resistance value of R9 (as shown in the graph). The black dashed line represents the output relationship without R8. It appears that introducing R8 allows for gain adjustment in the circuit.
Could someone explain the purpose of this design and why adding R8 might be beneficial?


Can you edit the question to add a link to where the circuit was found, as that may provide some content to the design decision.

Hicecream - Hi, As commented above, where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

I disassembled a Japanese medical device and found that one of its temperature measurement boards was designed this way. I then conducted a simulation based on this circuit board.

R8 affects the linearity in the relationship of output voltage vs. input resistance (R9).
Without R8 it would be somewhat nonlinear (convex) because R6 is not a constant current source (and there is a slight loading from R1+R2). The current through R6 will decrease as R9 increases in value (and a bit more current will flow through R1+R2). So we could just straighten out that curve.
However, the relationship of temperature vs. resistance for a platinum RTD is also convex.
By picking a specific value of R8 it is possible to compensate (approximately) for the both sources of nonlinearity and get linear voltage vs. temperature.
In fact it is possible to make the error zero at any three temperatures. You might pick  zero, full-scale and mid-scale or something else depending on the application. There will be some nominal error at other temperatures, typically much less for narrow spans, and often little enough to be considered neglible compared to other sources of error.
In the past we used this kind of circuit, however modern designs often use a real current source (especially if an analog front end chip is used) and usually digitize the voltage so that an equation such as Callendar-Van Dusen or a lookup table can be used by an MCU to completely eliminate nonlinearity as a significant source of error. There's no necessity to use a real current source, you could use a resistor and compensate for both effects digitally almost as easily. That does introduce a slight linearity dependency on the exact value of the reference voltage (Vdd in this circuit) vs. resistor tolerances, which can either be compensated for or ignored.

As can be seen in your diagram, the addition of the additional resistor R8 enhances the sensitivity of the whole circuit to temperature variations (resp variations of R9).
This is a typical effect of positive feedback (caused by R8).
Advantage: The sensitivity can be varied and adapted to different requirements using one single resistor. Without this resistor R8, a parallel variation of two resistors (R1, R4 or R2,R3) would be necessary.

As already pointed by @Spehro 'speff' Pefhany, R8 affects linearity
and "distorts" somewhat the function vo = f(R9) and so the function of Temperature.
Made with microcap v12 ... Note that "labels" are not the same, sorry.
The "red" line is a "straight" line ...
You can then see the change of linearity.


As already mentioned, the bridge itself is non linear with respect to the variable resistance. Besides that, as the equivalent resistances of each branch of the bridge differ, so do the effective values of R2 and R3, so the differential amplifier mismatch increases, which results in common mode gain.
Compare the 3 simulations to the linear reference (the resistance, at the top curve), exaggerating on the resistance variation:

The red curve shows the circuit "compensated" with the positive feedback (R8).
The other two compare what an ideal differential amplifier would provide (light green) with a real one (with perfectly matched resistors, without input buffers) without the compensation (blue).
